# Highcharts - gap between series in stacked area chart

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

I've created a stacked area chart in Highcharts, which you can see in the image below and in the following jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/m3dLtmoz/

[image: 2]

I have a workaround for the gaps you see, which is to group the data for each series by month so that each series looks something like this instead:

```
    series: [{
        data: [
            [1464739200000,2471],
            [1467331200000,6275],
            [1470009600000,2574],
            [1472688000000,7221],
            [1475280000000,3228]
        ]}
    ]
```

While the above isn't exactly what I'm going for, the way the series above is structured does give me what I ultimately want, which is this: 
[image: 3]

I'm really dying to know why the original setup isn't working appropriately, however.  I've tested other instances where datetimes group and aggregate properly based on a single datetime x axis value.  I'm stumped as to why this particular data set isn't working.  I've tried using the dataGrouping option in the Highstock library, but wasn't able to integrate that effectively.  I've messed with options as far as tickInterval goes to no avail.  I tried setting the "stacking: 'normal' option in each series instead of in the plotOptions, but that made no difference.  I've seen issues on github dealing with the stacked area charts, but nothing seems to exactly match up with what I'm seeing.  Any help is appreciated - thank you much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive the [error](http://www.highcharts.com/errors/15) in the console. Most of the series require data to be sorted in ascending order. Stacking has nothing do to it, see [example](http://jsfiddle.net/m3dLtmoz/6/).

Series which do not require data to be sorted are scatter or polygon. [No error in scatter](http://jsfiddle.net/m3dLtmoz/7/)

You should sort and group the points on your own. If you want to group them by months you have to prepare the data before you put them in a chart. The example below takes averages from the same datetime.

```
function groupData(unsortedData) {
    var data = unsortedData.slice();
    data.sort(function (a, b) {
      return a[0] - b[0]
    });


    var i = 1,
      len = data.length,
      den = 1,
      sum = data[0][1],
      groupedData = [[data[0][0], sum]],
      groupedData = [];

  for (; i < len; i++) {
    if (data[i - 1][0] === data[i][0]) {
      sum += data[i][1];
      den++;
    } else {
      groupedData.push([data[i - 1][0], sum / den]);
      den = 1;
      sum = data[i][1];
    }
  }

  groupedData.push([data[i-1][0], sum / den]);
  return groupedData;
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/e4enhw9a/1/

Comment: Nothing like a second set of eyes!  Thank you for your detailed answer!